# Is a passport needed for traveling by plane in Mexico? (Non-international flight)

Tags: air-travel, passports, mexico

I am going to be driving into Tijuana to board a flight that will take me to Acapulco. My flight is from Tijuana to Acapulco. Both locations are in Mexico. Will I need to have a passport in order to attend the flight, even though the flight is from one place in Mexico to another? I heard that in this situation, a passport is not required, but a passport may be required upon reentering the US. Would other documents be sufficient for boarding this flight? I will be returning from Acapulco to Tijuana, and from there I will be driving back across the border to the U.S.

Comment: I flew into mexico city from tJ with just using my Oregon state Id and will actually be flying back to mexico city next Thursday!!! You want to NOT deal with aeromexico because i was turned down by them for my ticket i purchased because i had no passport, but people have told me to not deal with them.... I suppose at the airport they can pretty much do what they want, but it doesn't really seem to be an issue with them fly volaris and you are good to go!!!!!...

Answer (score 5):

[This infographic](http://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs), on the website of the Mexico City airport, says that foreigners need a valid passport to travel on a domestic flight.  (Mexican citizens can alternatively use a driver's license or voter ID.)

Answer (score 2):

I just got back from vacation on 8/6/2014 to Cancun. We (all USA born citizens) crossed the border into Reynosa Mexico by car and boarded a plane from Reynosa Mexico to Cancun Mexico. I used my driver's license, my brother his passport book and my sister the passport card (you know the one that reads only valid for land and sea). My nephew used his long birth certificate to board the plane. So to answer your question yes you can travel by plane WITHIN Mexcio just using your driver's license or official USA ID.
You will need a an FMM/tourist card if you are traveling outside the "border area", I was the only one in my family asked for it on our return flight. Also if you plan on buying Pesos then yes you will need a passport book or passport card, they would not accept my driver's license (Texas). The return flight was the same, just for kicks we all used different methods of showing identification and they all worked (DL, passport book and card all worked). Driving back to the USA we were asked for passport card or book at the border crossing. I have in the past crossed (by land) with my driver's license but was told to get my passport book or card the next time I cross.

Comment: Carlos, did you get the FMM/tourist card with your ID or passport?