# What documentation does a Mexican citizen need to fly domestically within Mexico?

Tags: air-travel, legal, paperwork, domestic-travel, mexican-citizens

If a Mexican citizen, residing in Mexico, wants to fly domestically, what documents are needed?

Example: Flying from Torreon to Cancun (different states in Mexico)

Comment: The best place to look would be the airline website - it'll say what's acceptable there. I don't know Mexico but for domestic flights elsewhere you generally need government-issued ID, but not necessarily a passport. e.g. [VivaAerobus](https://www.vivaaerobus.com/en/flying-with-viva/before-your-flight) list (the 'Important documentation' section): IFE, Passport, Professional license, IMSS card or drivers license. You probably want an answer from someone Mexican though.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/29149/is-a-passport-needed-for-traveling-by-plane-in-mexico-non-international-flight

Answer (score 5):

[According to the FAQ page of the Mexico City International airport, Mexican citizens require ID to fly domestically within Mexico:](http://www.aicm.com.mx/en/passengers/faqs)

> [image: Mexico City International Airport infographics on travel documents]

A valid ID can be one of:

- voter ID
- passport
- driver's licence

Comment: Sometimes it's like you're just waiting for bounties before you answer ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo Who? Me? :)