# Flying within Mexico with no passport

Tags: air-travel, passports, paperwork, mexico, domestic-travel

Do I need a passport if I’m flying out of Tijuana to Mexico City? I will be driving into Tijuana and not using the CBX bridge

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What documentation does a Mexican citizen need to fly domestically within Mexico?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66313/what-documentation-does-a-mexican-citizen-need-to-fly-domestically-within-mexico)

Comment: @CatchAsCatchCan there's nothing in the question that indicates the traveler is a Mexican citizen.  Peter Villalobos: what is your citizenship?