# Traveling to GDL from Mexicali, I'm a US Citizen

Tags: international-travel, us-citizens, mexico

I just recently bought tickets to travel from Mexicali to Guadalajara. However, I am a US Citizen and I live in the US. I am just crossing the border by foot, and catching a flight in Mexico to go to GDL (since they're why cheaper in Mexico) However, do I need some type of Mexican paperwork indicating I am traveling within Mexico? Or can I just use my American Identification to board the flight?

Comment: As I understand it, at the time you cross the border by foot, you need to specifically [apply for an FMM](https://www.inm.gob.mx/fmme/publico/en/solicitud.html) using your US passport (a regular passport, not a passport card).  This is required by Mexican law although it [may not always be checked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/34949/74437).